# External Webpage Sends me to Apache Welcome Page not Flask App

Tags: python, python-3.x, apache, flask, mod-wsgi

I built an app in Flask which I can view on my internal IP address when I am on my network.

I have opened my ports and verified that I can see any static webpage on my external IP address, but I can't get that external IP address to point to my flask app instead of the static webpages in that folder.

Here is my `__init__.py` file

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

if __name__ == '__main__':
  app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=80)

from app import routes
```

Here is my config file for apache

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
            ServerName <<YOUR IP ADDRESS>>
            WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/proj/config.wsgi
            <Directory /var/www/proj/flaskapp/>
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
            </Directory>
            Alias /static /var/www/proj/flaskapp/static
            <Directory /var/www/proj/flaskapp/static/>
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
            </Directory>
            ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
            LogLevel warn
            CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
    </VirtualHost>
```

**The ultimate goal is to have a domain a bought via google to direct to this flask app**. I was able to get that to work when serving static webpages via apache, but not when switching to flask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently you need to disable the default screen first with the following command:

```
sudo a2dissite 000-default.conf
```

and then restart the server:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```